# DynamoDB not fetching all entries in case of two autogenerated attributes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, crud, dynamodb-mapper

I have a crud application which uses DynamoDb, it has a model class containing two autogenerated attributes, one for primary key and another for timestamp.
I am using `scan()` function of DynamoDbMapper to getAll entries from the db but getting below error.

`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: expected N in value {S: 2022-12-09T09:23:52.737Z,}`

**Employee**

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String employeeId;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String firstName;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String lastName;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String email;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private Department department;

    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy = DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
    private Long timestamp;
}
```

**DynamoDbConfiguration**

```java
package com.dailycodebuffer.config;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class DynamoDbConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper() {
        return new DynamoDBMapper(buildAmazonDynamoDB());
    }

    private AmazonDynamoDB buildAmazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                                "endpoint",
                                "region"
                        )
                )
                .withCredentials(
                        new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                                new BasicAWSCredentials(
                                        "access_key",
                                        "secret_key"
                                )
                        )
                )
                .build();
    }

}
```

Method to getAll the entries

```java
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return dynamoDBMapper.scan(Employee.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression());
    }
```

**DynamoDb dependency :**

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.857</version>
        </dependency>
```

***Note: If i remove the timestamp, getAll works perfectly fine.***

I am new to DynamoDb, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to take a random guess at this one, but I believe the issue is that you have an item (or several) which have stored a value for `timestamp` as a String, perhaps you inserted them into the table manually?

Now when you read back those items in the `Scan`, DynamoDB Mapper is trying to marshall against your class, which states that `timestamp` should be a `Long`, however, the item is showing a `String`.

My suggestion is to take a look through your table to see if such an item exists, which is causing your `Scan` to fail. Another quick way to check is my setting `Limit` on the Scan to 1, and see if there are no exceptions (hopefully the first item isn't the broken one :-/ )

Comment: Thanks! for the answer, I took a look at the table and found that the schema changed since i added the timestamp later on just to check my usecase.
Thanks again :D